# How to make Semantic UI react Search use id instead of title as key

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI react's Search module.

The user is supposed to be able to search for companies name.

Semantic UI react seems to use the title prop as a key when rendering the array of results. Some companies have the same name (located at different locations) but then React throws an error because of duplicate keys.

How can I make Semantic UI React use an Id or something else then the title as key when rendering the results?

```
const resultRenderer = ({ title, id }) => {
  console.log(id);
  return <div key={id}>{title}</div>;
};

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.timer = null;
  }

  handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);

    const { updateSearchValue } = this.props;

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      updateSearchValue(value);
      this.calculateSuggestions(value);
    }, 500);
  };

  calculateSuggestions = value => {
    const { resetSearch, fetchingSuggestions, getResults } = this.props;
    const { fetched } = this.props.search;
    if (value.length === 0) {
      resetSearch();
    } else if (value.length === 1 && !fetched) {
      getResults();
    } else if (value.length === 1 && fetched) {
      fetchingSuggestions();
    } else {
      fetchingSuggestions();
    }
  };

  handleResultSelect = (e, { result }) => {};

  render() {
    const { isLoading, suggestions, value } = this.props.search;
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={8}>
          <Search
            loading={isLoading}
            onSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}
            results={suggestions}
            value={value}
            resultRenderer={resultRenderer}
          />
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

> index.js:2177 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key,
>   `Dynjandi`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their
>   identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be
>   duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could
>   change in a future version.
>       in div (created by SearchResults)
>       in SearchResults (created by Search)
>       in div (created by Search)
>       in Search (at SearchBox.js:50)
>       in div (created by GridColumn)
>       in GridColumn (at SearchBox.js:49)
>       in div (created by Grid)
>       in Grid (at SearchBox.js:48)
>       in SearchBox (created by Connect(SearchBox))
>       in Connect(SearchBox) (at App.js:10)
>       in div (created by Container)
>       in Container (at App.js:9)
>       in App (at index.js:24)
>       in Provider (at index.js:23)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error can resolved by adding a property `key` to each item in the `suggestions` array that is passed to the `results` prop of `<Search />`. If `id` is a unique property on your `suggestions` array items, you can use something like `Array.prototype.map()` to add property `key` to each item and set the value to that of the respective `id` for that item.

The below example is using the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to merge each suggestion with a new `key` property targeting `id` of each suggestion.

```
const newSuggestions = suggestions.map(s => ({ ...s, key: s.id }));
```

Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hsqdtb) to a functioning example with a method handling search change events using `map()` to add a `key` property to each result that passed into `<Search />` prop `results`: